# Windows command to find and extract second or last occurance of text block

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

Looking for a Windows solution using command line or VBScript to take a file and find a second block of text and save that to its own file. Unfortunately, our user base uses Windows clients only so Linux is not an option. Would also like a original Microsoft solution without 3rd party tools.

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
subject=/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
issuer=/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEIDCCAwigAwIBAgIQNE7VVyDV7exJ9C/ON9srbTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
Q2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWNlcyBEaXZpc2lvbjE4MDYGA1UECxMvKGMpIDIw
MDYgdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuIC0gRm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxHzAdBgNV
BAMTFnRoYXd0ZSBQcmltYXJ5IFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMDYxMTE3MDAwMDAwWhcNMzYw
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/O=Thawte, Inc./CN=Thawte SSL CA
issuer=/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEbDCCA1SgAwIBAgIQTV8sNAiyTCDNbVB+JE3J7DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
Q2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWNlcyBEaXZpc2lvbjE4MDYGA1UECxMvKGMpIDIw
MDYgdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuIC0gRm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxHzAdBgNV
BAMTFnRoYXd0ZSBQcmltYXJ5IFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMjAw
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

However, I am only interested in the **second** or the **last** block of text that meets the following criteria:

Begins with: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` all the data in between and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Please note the block of text between the headers will always be different but the headers will remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RegExp (start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236360(v=vs.84).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/193ztwkw(v=vs.84).aspx)) that gets non-empty 'everything' non-greedily `[\s\S]+?` between the separators. Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
reCut.Global = True
reCut.Pattern = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n([\s\S]+?)\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\39463295.txt").ReadAll())
Dim sBlock : sBlock = oMTS(oMTS.Count - 1).SubMatches(0)
WScript.Echo ">>>" & sBlock & "<<<"
```

output:

```
cscript 39463295.vbs
>>>MIIEbDCCA1SgAwIBAgIQTV8sNAiyTCDNbVB+JE3J7DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
Q2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWNlcyBEaXZpc2lvbjE4MDYGA1UECxMvKGMpIDIw
MDYgdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuIC0gRm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxHzAdBgNV
BAMTFnRoYXd0ZSBQcmltYXJ5IFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMjAw<<<
```

**Update wrt comment:**

To include the separators:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
reCut.Global = True
reCut.Pattern = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----[\s\S]+?-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\39463295.txt").ReadAll())
Dim sBlock : sBlock = oMTS(oMTS.Count - 1).Value
WScript.Echo ">>>" & sBlock & "<<<"
```

output:

```
cscript 39463295b.vbs
>>>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEbDCCA1SgAwIBAgIQTV8sNAiyTCDNbVB+JE3J7DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
Q2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBTZXJ2aWNlcyBEaXZpc2lvbjE4MDYGA1UECxMvKGMpIDIw
MDYgdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuIC0gRm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxHzAdBgNV
BAMTFnRoYXd0ZSBQcmltYXJ5IFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMjAw
-----END CERTIFICATE-----<<<
```

(no more need of groups/SubMatches or EOL removal)

Comment: Thank you for this. Apologies if it wasnt clear in my post but I need to keep the header and footer in the output.